# reading GPU-Z shared memory

Tags: delphi, memory, shared

i'm trying to read information from [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) shared memory, but i'm doing something wrong. I've managed to translate the shared memory structure posted on [TechPowerUp](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=65258) forums. I can read all the `GPUZ_RECORD` but not the `GPUZ_SENSOR_RECORD`. Any help will be apreciated. Thank you!

**LATER EDIT I:**

if i use `packet record` instead i don`t get the AV anymore, but i still can't get the sensors info.

**LATER EDIT II:**

If i read the `data` from 0 to 128 (129 elements), then the 128 element is the first sensor and i can see the data correctly. :(

```
const
  MAX_RECORDS = 128;

GPUZ_RECORD = record
  key: array[0..255] of WChar;
  value: array[0..255] of WChar;
end;

GPUZ_SENSOR_RECORD = record
  name: array[0..255] of WChar;
  units: array[0..7] of WChar;
  digits: Cardinal;
  value: double;
end;

GPUZ_SH_MEM = record
  version : Cardinal;
  busy: Boolean;
  lastUpdate: Cardinal;
  data: array [0..MAX_RECORDS] of GPUZ_RECORD;
  sensors: array [0..MAX_RECORDS] of GPUZ_SENSOR_RECORD;
end;

PGPUZ_SH_MEM = ^GPUZ_SH_MEM;
```

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
procedure TMainForm.readSensors;
var
  hMapFile: Thandle;
  sKey, sVal: string;
  GPUInfo: PGPUZ_SH_MEM;
  s, d: integer;
begin
  hMapFile := OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, 'GPUZShMem');
  if hMapFile <> 0 then begin
    log(['Mapping succesfully']);;
    GPUInfo := MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
//    ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetLastError));
    if GPUInfo <> nil then begin

       log([ GPUInfo^.version ]);
       log([ GPUInfo^.busy ]);
       log([ GPUInfo^.lastUpdate ]);

       log(['LOGING DATA ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~']);
       for d:= 0 to Pred(MAX_RECORDS) do begin

         sKey := GPUInfo^.data[d].key;
         sVal := GPUInfo^.data[d].value;    
         if sKey <> '' then log([d, '#: ', sKey, sVal ]);

       end;
       log(['LOGING SENSORS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~']);
       for s:= 0 to Pred(MAX_RECORDS) do begin

         sKey := GPUInfo^.sensors[s].name; // i get an AV here when s:=127
         log([ 'Sensor ', s, '#: ', sKey ]);

//         sVal := TPN^.sensors[s].units;
//         log([ 'Unit: ', sVal ]);
//         log(['Digits: ', TPN^.sensors[s].digits ]);
//         log(['Value: ', TPN^.sensors[s].value ]);
       end;

    end else log([ 'Could not map that zone!' ]);

  end else begin
    log(['Could not find the zone for mapping...']);
    UnmapViewOfFile(GPUInfo);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
  end;
end;
```

log() is a small procedure defined like this:

```
procedure log( vData: array of Variant );
```

Comment: So GPU-Z is a benchmark program and you're accessing shared memory via a memory mapped file?  A bit of background would make your question a bit less of a mystery.  You really expect people here to figure out what you're talking about without explanation?  Help others help you.

Comment: Well, i thought GPU-Z is a very well know video card information program, seems my assumption was wrong, i`m sorry. My problem is that i can`t read the `GPUZ_SENSOR_RECORD` right for some reason. Maybe i didn`t translate the shared memory layout correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, a friend helped me to spot the error in my code, as i suspected my translation wasn't flawless, so i'll port the corrected code in case anybody is interested.

```
const
  MAX_RECORDS = 127; // <-- important [0..127] => 128 elements

GPUZ_RECORD = packed record // <-- all records must be packed
  key: array[0..255] of WChar;
  value: array[0..255] of WChar;
end;

GPUZ_SENSOR_RECORD = packed record // <-- all records must be packed
  name: array[0..255] of WChar;
  units: array[0..7] of WChar;
  digits: Cardinal;
  value: double;
end;

GPUZ_SH_MEM = packed record // <-- all records must be packed
  version : Cardinal;
  busy: Boolean;
  lastUpdate: Cardinal;
  data: array [0..MAX_RECORDS] of GPUZ_RECORD;
  sensors: array [0..MAX_RECORDS] of GPUZ_SENSOR_RECORD;
end;

PGPUZ_SH_MEM = ^GPUZ_SH_MEM;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a structure alignment or pascal API/struct translation issue. Did you check SizeOf(GPUZ_SENSOR_RECORD) in C and see if it matches sizeof(GPUZ_SENSOR_RECORD) in pascal? Did you try changing alignment?

Comment: it was a problem with my translation of the C code, thank you for your input.